# Move just 1 match stick to make the 2 equations right

Tags: mathematics, lateral-thinking, matches

Move just 1 match to new position to make these 2 equations right.

[image]

Comment: Are matches allowed to cross?

Comment: @boboquack : Yes. Anything you can do by moving just 1 match to make those equations right

Comment: And do the two equations have to remain two equations or can they be inequalities or even just numbers?

Comment: What I mean is "two equations have to remain two equations, no inequalities", but, creative answer is welcome.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The trick is to

> turn the equations upside down.
>  [image]

Comment: how is that possible without moving ALL the matches?

Comment: @Jasen: Walk to the other side of the table.